# Vue3 composition API - how to update user object?

Tags: vuejs3, vue-composition-api

I am just learning to code and I cannot get this working.
Could you please help me and tell me how to update var user object with value that is passed through this function:

```
function fillUserForm (tmpUser) {
  UserFormContainer.value.openForm()
  user.value = { 
    username: tmpUser.username,
    email: tmpUser.email,
    special_deals: tmpUser.special_deals,
    offer_cycle: tmpUser.offer_cycle, 
  };
}
```

This is the complete setup part of the code:

```
setup() {
const isSubscribed = ref(false);
const UserFormContainer = ref();
const userList = ref([]);
var user = ref({
  username: "",
  email: "",
  special_deals: ref(false),
  offer_cycle: "",
});

function showPopup() {
  isSubscribed.value = !isSubscribed.value;
}

const closePopup = () => {
  isSubscribed.value = false;
  UserFormContainer.value.openForm();
};

fetch("http://localhost:8003/api/users/")
  .then((resp) => resp.json())
  .then((resp) => {
    userList.value = resp.data;
  });

function saveSubscriber(subscriber) {
  user.value = {
    username: subscriber.username,
    email: subscriber.email,
    special_deals: subscriber.special_deals,
    offer_cycle: subscriber.offer_cycle,
  };
  fetch("http://localhost:8003/api/users", {
    method: "POST",
    headers: {
      "Content-Type": "application/json",
      "Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "http://localhost:8003",
    },
    body: JSON.stringify(user.value),
  })
    .then((resp) => resp.json())
    .then((resp) => {
      if (!resp.error) {
        console.log(user)
        user.value.id = resp.data.insertId;
        userList.value.push({
          ...user.value,
        });
        console.log(userList.value)
      }
    });
}

function deleteUser(userId) {
  fetch(`http://localhost:8003/api/users/${userId}`, {
    method: "DELETE",
  })
    .then((resp) => resp.json())
    .then(() => {
      userList.value = userList.value.filter((user) => user.id !== userId);
    });
}

function fillUserForm (tmpUser) {
  UserFormContainer.value.openForm()
  user.value = { 
    username: tmpUser.username,
    email: tmpUser.email,
    special_deals: tmpUser.special_deals,
    offer_cycle: tmpUser.offer_cycle, 
  };
}
```

I get the tmpUser parameter from

```
<tr v-for="user in userList" :key="user.id">
   <td>{{ user.id }}</td>
   <td>{{ user.username }}</td>
   <td>{{ user.email }}</td>
   <td>{{ user.special_deals }}</td>
   <td>{{ user.offer_cycle }}</td>
   <td>
    <button
     class="subscriber-table__update-btn"
     @click="fillUserForm(user)"
     >
     x
    </button>
   </td>
```

Comment: Please consider to create [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) using some sandbox.

Answer (score 0):

If you define your `UserFormContainer`  as `const UserFormContainer = ref();`

How could be there an `openForm()` function`? There is no such function in your code.